# I am currently retrieving the path of the image, how can I retrieve the image itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm using asp.net so there is no picturebox.

```html
protected void lnk_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int AdvertisementID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ViewByID", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdvertisementID", AdvertisementID);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        sqlCon.Close();
        hfContactID.Value = AdvertisementID.ToString();
        AdsTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["AdvertisementID"].ToString();
        itemTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["Item"].ToString();
        ImageTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["ImgPath"].ToString();
        ButSave.Text = "Update";
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jia, can you show us what have your tried? A simple google search will give you all the details

Comment: @JiaHao,  please take a look at the answer I have just posted with detailed explanation.

Comment: @JiaHao, Please mark it as answer, if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add an image control to your aspx page using markup like below.

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"  AlternateText="Image text"  ImageAlign="left" />
```

Then, in your code-behind which you have provided in your post, you simply set the image url for above image control as shown in code below. (look at the line of code just after  the comment saying `//set image url of image control to display the image`).

NOTE: I am assuming that `dtbl.Rows[0]["ImgPath"].ToString()` contains the file name of image as well as the *full/relative virtual path* to the image file. For example, if the image file is located under Images folder from the current page location then the relative path would be `Images/imagename.jpg` or you can give the full virtual path from root like `~/Images/imagename.jpg`.

```
protected void lnk_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int AdvertisementID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("ViewByID", sqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdvertisementID", AdvertisementID);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
        sqlCon.Close();
        hfContactID.Value = AdvertisementID.ToString();
        AdsTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["AdvertisementID"].ToString();
        itemTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["Item"].ToString();
        ImageTb.Text = dtbl.Rows[0]["ImgPath"].ToString();
        //set image url of image control to display the image
        Image1.ImageUrl =  ImageTb.Text;
        ButSave.Text = "Update";
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
    }
```